# Can I use projecting bolt shield anchors in AAC concrete blocks?

Tags: anchor

I just bought a 60” TV, and a very heavy duty bracket to attach it to the wall. The wall itself is made of aerated autoclaved concrete blocks, and I have read you need to be careful about what kind of anchors you use in these lightweight blocks.

The TV stand came with 6 very strong-looking bolts, which I’ve read are called shield anchor projecting bolts. They look like this:

[image: projecting bolt]

In my local hardware store the anchors labelled as AAC-compatible look far smaller and weaker, made of plastic, so I’d like to use these projecting bolts if possible, but I haven’t been able to find any information tells me that it would be safe to do so.